# sublime text 2 setting custom code highlight

Tags: coding-style, editor, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2

I was using notpad++ till now and now using sublime text 2.

Sublime Text 2 has curly bracket matches with just underline beneath them which is not clearly visible to me and I want to change it to either bold or highlighted with a background color.

Are there possibilities to define it in its preference or settings ?

Comment: Thanks @Bahdan I am not focusing on color scheme I want to hightlight curly brackets and their match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what you're looking for.
You need to install the **[BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter)** package.
I'd suggest you install the **[Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation)** for ST2 first to make your installation smooth.

I hope this will help you.

**EDIT**

You don't have to download the package, just install the Package control and install BracketHighlighter from the Package Control.

Regards,

Comment: Hmm... this is cool I can see lot more packages there, thanks. I hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, Preferences => Color Scheme

Comment: Still in same situation, underline is not visible much as curly are single character and their underline is to short to be visible in first view.